# Ошибка при имитировании нажатий клавиш на vds

Tags: c#, процесс, vps, windows-server, vds

пишу программу которая будет делать имитации нажатия клавиш на vds.
вот код:

```
Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
process.WaitForInputIdle();
SendKeys.SendWait("k");
Console.ReadLine();
```

если я нахожусь на своем vds то все работает, как только я отключаюсь, появляется эта ошибка:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendInput(Byte[] oldKeyboardState, Queue previousEvents)
at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String keys, Control control, Boolean wait)
at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(String keys)
at MyProgram.Program.Main()
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: откуда отключаетесь, куда отключаетесь, зачем отключаетесь? каким именно образом подключаетесь? RDP? VNC?

Comment: @aepot подключаюсь по rdp, отключаюсь от  своего vds, я же не буду постоянно подключенным к vds

Comment: RDP десктоп отключается вместе с вами. Ввод в отключенную сессию невозможен, винда защищается от атак. Подключайтесь к локальной консоли сервера,а не по RDP.

Comment: @aepot а как мне к ней подключиться?

Comment: А как вы винду ставили, это же VDS а не VPS? Это у хостинг-провайдера можно узнать, например через VNC.

Comment: @aepot подключился через VNC, если я отключусь перестанет работать?

Comment: VNC - это как монитор с клавой, если вы выключите монитор у компа, он перестанет работать? Вы попробовать пробовали?